# How can I get JavaScript intellisense to show in VS Code whenever the file is not open?

Tags: javascript, file, visual-studio-code, ide, intellisense

In VS Code, whenever I have a javascript file open and am using code that is in that file on a different javascript file it gives me javascript intellisense, but whenever I close the first file and keep righting code that was in that file, the intellisense goes away. How can I keep the javascript intellisense showing even if the file is closed? Is there some type of setting I can add in vs code to give me intellisense from a specific directory in my folder? I am not using Node or anything, only using vanilla javascript.

I have tried to export and import the module to give intellisense to the other file but exporting and importing is something my team wants to try to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If your team doesn't want to use `import` etc, you will need to give VS Code some hint on where to find the file.

You could use the Tripple Slash Directive,..

eg.

Let's say we have a file call `test.js`

```
function Test(x) { console.log(x) }
```

And want to get types from another file in same directory.

```
/// <reference path="./test.js" />

var n = Test()  //<-- here VS Code knows it takes a parameter called `x`
```

A little bonus too, if you add `// @ts-check` to the start of this file you can even get some type checking too.

eg.

```
// @ts-check
/// <reference path="./test.js" />
var n = Test(1,2)  //<--- Error 0-1 arguments expected got 2.
```

Later you could even make this have even better type checking / intelisense.

```
/**
 * @param {number} x provide a number
 */
function Test(x) { console.log(x) }



// @ts-check
/// <reference path="./test.js" />
var n = Test('22')  //<--- Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
```

Another option, you could also try setting your `jsconfig.json`  include options to prevent having to use the tripple slash,  one gotcha potentially here is VS Code will have more working in finding the definitions, so for large projects might have some performance considerations.
eg.

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "include": [
        "**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That does work, I am curious though. Could this also be solved also with adding a jsconfig.json file to our project and give a path here to where the javascript lives and that would give us intellisense globally in the project without having to use the reference?

Comment: @AndrewConstancio  I believe so yes,.. I'll update